# How to properly set component state during onChange call in React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, setstate

I have a component 'CheckboxGroup' which has an onChange() function called when a checkbox is clicked. How can I update the state for 'selectedValues' during this call to onChange()?

```
export const CheckboxWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    return (
        <Window>     
            <CheckboxGroup
                onChange={(checked, value) => {
                    if (checked && !selectedValues.includes(value)) {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedValues: [...this.state.selectedValues, value],
                        });
                    } else if (!checked && selectedValues.includes(value)) {
                        setSelectedValues(selectedValues.filter(val => val != value));
                    }
                }}
            />
        </Window>
    );
};
```

I am getting the error:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'
> for 'this.setState' and 'this.state'.

setSelectedValues in the else if seems to compile fine however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing class and function components. Since you are using a functional component, you should not be using the `this` keyword, or the `setState` function. In fact, the second item in the array returned from `useState` is how you will update state in a functional component:

```js
if (checked && !selectedValues.includes(value)) {
    setSelectedValues(prev => [...prev, value])
}
```

Comment: that clears it up, thanks!